Why my form dont display error (file size)
In my Symfony 6.4 project, I have a form with a file input and a maxSize set to 5M. On my web server in development mode (Symfony) with PHP 8.3.6, if I try to upload a file that's 20M, the form displays the message set in maxSizeMessage
However, on my production server (Apache 2, PHP 8.3.6), the form does not display the message set in maxSizeMessage.
            ->add(
                'file',
                FileType::class,
                [
                    "required" => false,
                    "label" => "Ajout d'un document",
                    "multiple" => true,
                    "help" => "Formats : .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xlsx",
                    "constraints" => [
                        new All([
                            "constraints" => [
                                new File([
                                    "maxSize" => "5M",
                                    'maxSizeMessage' => "Le fichier est trop volumineux. La taille maximale autorisée est de 5 Mo.",
                                    'mimeTypes' => [
                                        'application/pdf',
                                        'text/csv',
                                        'application/msword',
                                        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                                        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                                    ],
                                    'mimeTypesMessage' => "Seuls les formats : .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xlsx sont autorisés.",
                                ])
                            ]
                        ])
                    ],
                    "attr" => [
                        "accept" => ".pdf,.csv,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx"
                    ]
                ]
            )

In my php.ini :
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 10M


I tried to change php.ini but no effect

Well.. what's the error message ?

Sorry, the error message is : "Sorry the file is too large". Just under the input file but this message is not displaying in production server when i try to upload a larger file

So you are saying it is explicitly not the error message you configured there for maxSizeMessage ...?

Sorry, I expressed myself badly. The message configured in maxSizeMessage does not appear on the production server

So what happens instead - are larger files simply getting accepted by the system, without any complaints? Or do you get a different error / other type of message?

No errors, no message. Just a refresh of my form page. And the files are not accepted by the system.
